# How to resolve these CloudKit Background Task Warnings

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have a functioning iOS app that is producing some troubling warning messages and I'd like to resolve them.

From the console:

```
Background Task 37 ("CoreData: CloudKit Import"), was created over 30 seconds ago. In applications running in the background, this creates a risk of termination. Remember to call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:) for your task in a timely manner to avoid this.
```

This warning is repeated periodically, however, each time with a different Task Id. I presume that if I can capture the Task Id, I could figure where to call

`UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:)`

I do not know if it's possible to obtain the Task Id. I do have a notification observer set to check for data changes. I'd prefer not to remove that.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({ () -> Void in
        self.fetchProjects()
    })
}
```

Comment: Does that really have to do with CloudKit?  I have never seen that kind of warning messages.  Isn't that probably related to Core Data?, which I don't use.

Comment: Hmm. I'm keeping a core data store synced using `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`. I'm honestly not sure whether it's CK or CoreData. I'll look for CoreData errors, but thanks for pointing this out.